# Extract text from script with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager

I've got a script like this on a webpage:

```
<script>
    window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = {"meReducer":{"me":{"id":1234,"groupId":789,"},},//more code removed};
</script>
```

and need to fire a tag through Google Tag Manager to store the "id" value as a GTM variable.

Is there any javascript that can grab text from within another script like this?

Comment: Do you have to get it from the other script? That script assigns the value to a global variable, so you should be able to reference the property key (`window.__INITIAL_STATE__.meReducer.me.id`).

Comment: @isherwood unfortunately yes. I have no access to modify the page itself except through a tag manager. So I need something in Google Tag Manager to grab it after the page loads and pass it to another application.

Comment: @isherwood ooohhh, I see what you're saying and am getting close. I can see that `Object.values( window.__INITIAL_STATE__.meReducer.me);` returns an array of values. Now I've just got to figure out how to parse out that ID value from the rest. It will still need to be fired through GTM, but this is a huge step forward for me. Thank you!!!

Comment: I think you can just create a custom javascript variable to get  window.__INITIAL_STATE__.meReducer.me.id || ""

Answer (score 2):

In GTM, create a new variable of "JavaScript Variable" type, in the field, put in `window.__INITIAL_STATE__.meReducer.me.id`, this is exactly as if you were going to reference it within javascript, like so:

[image]

After that you'll be able to use the variable name (in my case I called it "ME.ID") in other tags like so, note the double brackets:

[image]